# PHP Warning : file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, json

I have built a local DVD Database using Codeigniter, With film names etc in. What I am looking to do is load in more data for the film from [this IMDB API](http://imdbapi.com/).

However I am getting the following error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents(http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=2 Fast 2 Furious) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> Filename: controllers/dvd.php
>
> Line Number: 92

Copying [this URI](http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=2%20Fast%202%20Furious) into an address bar returns the json data, But when loading in my page it gives me that error.

It is worth noting I am running on a localhost this particular site. As I am just familiarising myself with Codeigniter.

My code is....

```
            // Send Query To IMDB Api

        $film_q = $film_name[0]->title;
        $imdb_uri = "http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=$film_q";
        $json = file_get_contents($imdb_uri);
        $json = json_decode($json);

        print_r($json);
```

*EDIT* : Looking further into this. Single word film names seem to load in ok, So I'm assuming I need to someway drill down a "+" into the spaces?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try `urlencode()`:

```
 $film_q   = urlencode($film_name[0]->title);
 $imdb_uri = "http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=$film_q";
```

Comment: Don't encode the entire url, that'll trash the real metachars. encode ONLY the $film_q part.

Comment: Hi, On that I am now getting "Call to undefined function url_encode()"

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot guys. I dont think I'd have ever gotten that

Answer (score 2):

You might consider running urlencode() on the movie title. It's possible that the spaces in "2 Fast 2 Furious" were left behind.

Your link should look like this.

```
http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=2%20Fast%202%20Furious
```

Not this.

```
http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=2 Fast 2 Furious
```